# Transpose Single Multiline cell horizontally with a Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on a macro that takes a multiline cell and takes each new line and puts them horizontally into the next column. ***This needs to be relative referenced, meaning I'll need to reuse it on multiple cells so it can't be specific to a certain range of cells.***

So what I start off with is this:[image: initial cell]

Then I should turn that into this:

[image]

I have tried writing a macro that takes all the values and puts them into individual cells on one column separated by rows, and then paste > transpose, but I get a paste error. Anybody got any tips? Thanks in advance.

Here's the code from the macro I've tried so far. I'm getting a paste error from it though, so it is not working.

```
Sub t()
'
' t Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+t
'
    ActiveCell.Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Sheryl D. Colvin, deceased" & Chr(10) & ""
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1:A3").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:A3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1:A3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: STOP YELLING, please.  If you want to emphasize your test use **Bold** or *Italics*

Comment: Wasn't yelling, just emphasizing a different way. Ha

Answer (score 1):

Merry Christmas

```
Sub splitcell()
Dim arr() As String
Dim rng as Range
set rng = selection
arr = Split(rng, Chr(10))
rng.Resize(, UBound(arr) + 1).Value = arr
End Sub
```

Put this in your module, then you can assign a shortcut key by going to Tools>Macro>Macros (Alt+F8), then select the Options button and enter in the shortcut key you would like to use.

Choose the cell you want to split then hit the short cut key you assign. voila its done.

Comment: Can this be used with relative reference?

Comment: @Oystermaker What do you mean by `relative reference`?  Most likely yes.

Comment: I need the macro to be able to start relative to a cell I have selected on the page. And do I just make a macro and paste this code in there? Because it seems like it will only work for the range `C1`

Comment: @Oystermaker, You are making me regret doing this, usually I do not answer unless some effort is shown by the OP.  But this was a simple one so I did it.  You can change the range to what ever you like.  You can loop through ranges and use what is here to do what you want.  This is just a backbone on which you will need to build the rest.  This code works for what you have shown and asked.  If you want more I need to see more.

Comment: Such a nice community.. Let me edit the question to further explain my needs then.. I have been working on this for hours now with no avail, but my attempts at solving the issue are farfetched and would not offer any help to someone trying to help me solve this.

Comment: @Oystermaker see the edit.  Now you call this for each range you want

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not know how to use this. I'm not very experienced in using methods with cells. How would I call this and define my range?